# ListView: Cannot order by type 'System.Object'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, listview, sorting

I'm trying to sort a column in a ListView using Lambda Expression but, when I try to bind the result to the list view, I'm getting this error.

Here is the code, I'm trying to use.

```
Private Sub BindCategories(Optional ByVal SortColumn As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal SortOrder As SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending)
    Dim DS As IQueryable(Of DataEntities.Category) = DataEntities.Category.GetAllItems
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn) Then
        DS = Sort(Of DataEntities.Category)(DS.AsEnumerable, SortColumn, SortDirection.Ascending).AsQueryable
    End If
    lstCategories.DataSource = DS
    lstCategories.DataBind()
End Sub
```

and here is the code for `Sort` function.

```
Private Function Sort(Of T)(ByVal src As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal columnName As String, ByVal orderby As SortDirection) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")

    Dim sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))(Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, columnName), GetType(Object)), param)

    Select Case orderby
        Case WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending
            Return src.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression)
        Case Else
            Return src.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(sortExpression)
    End Select
End Function
```

The error page shows that the error occurred at `lstCategories.DataBind()`

Source Error:

```
Line 15:         End If  
Line 16:         lstCategories.DataSource = DS 
Line 17:         lstCategories.DataBind()  << **Error occurs at the point.** 
Line 18:     End Sub 
Line 19:
```

**Stack Trace**

> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot order by type 'System.Object'.]
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(Expression
>   sequence, LambdaExpression expression, SqlOrderType orderType) +908326
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mc) +8217
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mc) +74
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>   +1003
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression
>   node) +79
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query,
>   SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +114
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) +132
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   +35    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection) +7667686    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +61
>   System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create(DataContext context,
>   IEnumerable`1 sequence) +53
>
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.GetNewBindingList() +51
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList()
>   +15    System.Web.UI.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(Object
>   dataSource, String dataMember) +50
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ReadOnlyDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String
>   viewName) +41
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView()
>   +128    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.GetData() +4
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +60
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +57
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
>   Admin_Categories.BindCategories(String SortColumn, SortDirection
>   SortOrder) in F:\Work\Under
>   Development\Websites\Smile\Smile-Deploy\Admin\Categories.aspx.vb:17
>   Admin_Categories.lstCategories_Sorting(Object sender,
>   ListViewSortEventArgs e) in F:\Work\Under
>   Development\Websites\Smile\Smile-Deploy\Admin\Categories.aspx.vb:65
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.OnSorting(ListViewSortEventArgs e)
>   +110    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleSort(String
>   sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection) +57
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleSort(String sortExpression)
>   +52    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e,
>   Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +268
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +233    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
>   +118    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +135
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +175    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Comment: That `GetType(Object)` is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: I finally resorted to Scott Guthrie's Dynamic LINQ method. Thanks anyway....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no comparison defined for the type `Object`. An object can be anything, how would you compare two objects without knowing what they are? For instance, you can't compare an int and a string... which is greater between `42` and `"Hello world"`?

So you need to know what you're comparing...